# IPv6 - Multiple routers and 'dealing' with NAT

Tags: networking, routing, ipv6

**Note:** I am not thinking of NAT on IPv6.

I have the following network setup made up of GNU/Linux boxes:

http://portablejim.now.im/images/network_diagram.png

Some network traffic is currently being passed through the VPN tunnel to the internet. Computer A is the VPN server THere can be more than 1 client on the VPN.

I am wanting to get the network ipv6 capable and am trying to understand how it would work. I currently only have a /64, however I can get a larger pool of addresses.

What I am wondering is:

- If I use the /64 and have A as a router, how will computers C and D know to route to the Internet out (from computer A).
- Can I have both A and B be routers, A advertising the global address as well as a ULA,  and B advertising a subnet ULA? Do I need something bigger than a /64?

Comment: How's your routing configured now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're going to need more than a /64 pool to do what you want to do. Each subnet should have its own /64 pool according to [RFC4291](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4291#section-2.5.1). I'm counting 3 subnets right now. So get a /48 allocation, assign a /64 to each subnet. The rest is just a matter of routing between networks. For something this small, you can just enter in static routes on each router.